# Activity zoom transition from button - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I am trying to implement activity transitions in my app. I came across an awesome one [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNF8pXr6whU). But it is only compatible with android jellybean +. The link above redirects to youtube where Nick Butcher shows Activity zoom transition from a view.

I want to use it on gingerbread (API 10)+. How can I achieve that? One idea which came to my mind was to take the location of that view on the screen, pass it to the upcoming activity and then ask that upcoming activity to zoom or grow bigger from that location. I don't know if that is possible or not. Any ideas or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this animation, and change XY according to your image position and screen size, and start your activity when the animation end, it's a trick, hope it help:

```
private void centerAndZoomView( View view)
    {
        RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.rootLayout );
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
        int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - root.getMeasuredHeight();

        int originalPos[] = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

        int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2;
        xDest -= (view.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
        int yDest = dm.heightPixels/2 - (view.getMeasuredHeight()/2) - statusBarOffset;

        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );

        Animation scale
          = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f,root.getMeasuredWidth()/view.getMeasuredWidth() , 1.0f, root.getMeasuredHeight()/view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                               Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                               Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        scale.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);

        set.addAnimation(scale);
        set.addAnimation(anim);

        set.setFillAfter(true);
        set.setDuration(10000);
        //set.start();


        view.startAnimation(set);
        set.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), NextActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "END OF ANIMATION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

I've combined TranslateAnimation and ScaleAnimation according to the screen width and height, you can pass any [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)(Button, ImageView, LinarLayout...) as parameter, and your root layout must have "rootLayout" id.

Comment: Looks great. But I am completey now to animation in android. Can you please tell me when to call it? I want to start a new activity on button click.

Comment: I want create it for you, but i'm at work :), then you can start here:  http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1019

Comment: Thanks! When you get time please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Activity.overridePendingTransition()` method and specify your own animations.  This has been available since API level 5.  The `ActivityOptions` Nick is using in the video is just a newer way of accomplishing the same thing and was introduced in API level 16.  Note that in order to support the older APIs you'll have to use an `Animation` resource (tween animation) instead of an `Animator` type.  You can do translation, alpha and zoom (scale) type animations.

Comment: I read about `overridePendingTransition()` but I don't think its possible to do what Nick is doing using this method. Can you please tell me a good site where this is explained or if you know it please help me!

Comment: I didn't get a chance to watch the entire video, so I can't comment on exactly what he's doing.  However, I have been able to use this approach without any issues doing my own custom animations.  What is he doing specifically that you believe is not possible?

Comment: The part in which he starts a new activity by zooming from a view